# Post Nested parameters using Curl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, postman

This is the Request body that I need to send- (Curl POST request in PHP)

```
$data = {
    "paramOne" : "f733787d-5649",
    "paramTwo": {
        "format": "123XD"
    },
    "paramThree": [
      {"type":"cn", "value":"Test User Manish 1"},
      {"type":"c", "value":"US"}
    ]
};
```

I'm trying to use it at this line of my Curl Request in PHP-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

The nested params are messing up the format in which I'm trying to send.

I already tried using **http_build_query** but then paramThree is causing problems.
I'm looking for the changes that I need to make to the format of $data before I use http_build_query on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JSON. You can either post it as a string (enclosed in quotes) or make an array first, convert it to JSON and then post it. Like this:

```
$array = [
    'paramOne' => 'f733787d-5649',
    'paramTwo' => [
        'format' => '123XD'
        ],
    'paramThree' => [[
        'type' => 'cn',
        'value' => 'Test User Manish 1'
        ],
        [
        'type' => 'c',
        'value' => 'US'
            ]]
    ];

$data = json_encode($array);
```

In both cases use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
```

Comment: Thanks 10 on 10! I think I tried to do all the things together. Should have kept the request body in array format and I wouldn't even need to use http_build_query in the first place.